# Angular Reactive Form - A Select field is not getting prepopulated

Tags: angular-reactive-forms

This may be a simple issue but I am stuck here. Can't spot my mistake.

This is a reactive form which is used for adding as well as editing a document.
While editing the url has 'id' as params. Based on which the document is retrieved from server and the data should be patched in the form. All is working fine except one select type field - i.e. docName - which is not getting populated.

Pls help me spot the error.

**html template**

```
      <mat-form-field style="width:30%">
        <mat-label>Document Name</mat-label>
        <mat-select matInput [(value)]="docNameVal" formControlName="docName">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let doc of docNames" [value]="doc.code">{{doc.name}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field> 
      &nbsp;
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Document Date</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="docDate" [(value)]="docDateVal"
          [matDatepicker]='DatePicker1'>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]='DatePicker1'></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #DatePicker1></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field> &nbsp;
```

**component.ts**

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.id = params['id'];
      this.editMode = params['id'] != null;
    });

    this.form = this.fb.group({
      docName: ['', Validators.required],
      docDate: ['', Validators.required],
      topicType: ['', Validators.required],
      topicText: ['', Validators.required],
    });

    if(this.editMode) {
      this.titleString = "EDITING"
      this.isLoading = true;
      this.docService.getDoc(this.id)
        .subscribe(
          result => {
            this.isLoading = false;
            this.doc = result;
            if (this.doc.items) {
              this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.doc.items);
              this.items = this.doc.items;
              this.recdDataSource = true;

              this.form.patchValue({
                docName: this.doc.docName,      // NOT WORKING
                docDate: this.doc.docDate,      // this WORKS
              });

              this.docNameVal = this.doc.docName;  // the same docName used somewhere else works.

            } else {
              this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.items);
              this.recdDataSource = true;
            }
          },
          err => {
            this.isLoading = false;
          }
          );
      } else {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.items);
        this.recdDataSource = true;
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem.

This was due to the fact that the data that was getting stored in docName property was full text and the value of the Select field was based on the code name of the docName. (ref line 4 in html template)

So, when retrieving data for editing a document, it was trying to put the full name in the value of the Select field. Hence, the issue. Therefore, instead of using code name and Full Name for the docName formControl, I made it a simple array of strings.